# How to restart Jenkins manually?

Tags: jenkins

I've just started working with Jenkins and have run into a problem. After installing several plugins it said it needs to be restarted and went into a "shutting down" mode, but never restarts.

How do I do a manual restart?

Comment: Note: "Jenkins is Shutting Down" doesn't actually shut down, it just notifies the various users that might want to build something that Jenkins is gonna be restarted soon.

Comment: Something to note that I didnt notice that anyone else mentioned...If you put Jenkins in shutdown mode it doesnt actually shut down, which has been mentioned. What wasn't noted is that it stops new builds from starting. If you need to let a build complete before you restart you should put Jenkins in shutdown mode, let your build finish, and then do your "restart" with whatever method you choose from above.

Comment: Since version 1.442 Jenkins **doesn't** require to be restarted after **installing** new plug-in(s), use *“Install without restart”*. Unfortunately this feature will not work for update or uninstall.

Answer (score 2299, accepted):

To restart Jenkins manually, you can use either of the following commands (by entering their URL in a browser):

`(jenkins_url)/safeRestart` - Allows all running jobs to complete. New jobs will remain in the queue to run after the restart is complete.

`(jenkins_url)/restart` - Forces a restart without waiting for builds to complete.

Comment: Is there an equivalen of the safeRestart but done using Shell command?

Comment: For safeRestart, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/15555339/260122 `java -jar /var/cache/jenkins/war/WEB-INF/jenkins-cli.jar -s http://localhost:8080/ safe-restart` (if installed by rpm or deb, otherwise adjust accordingly).

Comment: This causes a `RestartNotSupportedException` in Jenkins 1.532.1 with IcedTea 2.3.9. `sudo /etc/init.d/jenkins restart` worked for me though.

Comment: Neither restart nor safeRestart work in Windows, it throws a RestartNotSupportedException. I had to restart the whole Tomcat (ugly option, I know)

Comment: Tip: if you are using the Workflow plugin, `restart` will not kill running Workflow builds. In version 1.8 or later (requires Jenkins 1.609.1 or later), `safeRestart` will also go ahead and restart Jenkins even while Workflow builds are in progress (after any “traditional” builds complete).

Comment: In Windows, use the Windows service rather than the command line.

Comment: @Mag I agree. They mention the commands here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14869398/4620962 More details on installing as a service can be found here: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Installing+Jenkins+as+a+Windows+service

Comment: @Mag no side effects from restarting the Jenkins service so long as everything is idling and no pending changes have not yet been saved right?

Comment: Are there any internal links from jenkins to do this instead of rememebering magic url's?

Comment: do you know if doing the 2nd (unsafe option) in any way differs from simply rebooting the web server container that the Jenkins runs out of (e.g. Tomcat, Glassfish etc)?

Comment: In Linux, you have the `service jenkins restart` option, if you installed Jenkins with System V init scripts.

Comment: Is this not available in the web gui?

Comment: Be aware if Jenkins is deployed as a ".war" file within a running Tomcat, a Jenkins restart also restarts any other .war files in that Tomcat instance.

Comment: Is there no Button for that?

Comment: service jenkins restart solved my docker socket problem while restarting from browser did not.

Comment: How long does it usually take? I am waiting for 10 min already...

Comment: This is a handy way, especially if you don't have access to the Node where jenkins is actually running...

Comment: There is a Plugin called "Safe Restart Plugin" that you can install without restarting Jenkins. After installation you have a "Restart Safely" link on the "Manage Jenkins" page.

Answer (score 217):

If you installed as a *rpm* or *deb*, then `service jenkins restart` will work also.

Answer (score 132):

**This answer is very out of date:** it predates the adoption of systemd for Debian and its derivatives. For modern Debian derived systems, see the [Aamir's more recent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45877259/319266).

On Ubuntu or Debian, when installed through `apt-get`/`dpkg`:

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/jenkins restart
Usage: /etc/init.d/jenkins {start|stop|status|restart|force-reload}
```

Comment: [https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/216118748-How-to-Start-Stop-or-Restart-your-Instance-](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/216118748-How-to-Start-Stop-or-Restart-your-Instance-) says
    IMPORTANT : Do not launch methods start|stop|restart manually as $sudo /etc/init.d/jenkins start|stop|restart because it makes your service unreliable as it picks up the environment from the root user as opposed to a clean reliable blank environment that is set by the init launchers (service / systemctl).

Answer (score 109):

The [SafeRestart Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/SafeRestart+Plugin) needs to be mentioned. It is pretty useful (*Restart Safely*).  It adds a link to be able to restart from the main menu:

[image]

Comment: I often use this feature for plugin installs.

Comment: Bizarre that this plugin is not included by default.

Answer (score 91):

The below commands worked for me in [Red Hat Linux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Hat_Linux) and should work for Ubuntu also.

- To know the status of Jenkins:

  ```
  sudo service jenkins status
  ```
- To start the Jenkins:

  ```
  sudo service jenkins start
  ```
- To stop the Jenkins:

  ```
  sudo service jenkins stop
  ```
- To restart the Jenkins:

  ```
  sudo service jenkins restart
  ```

Demo on command prompt:

```
[root@varunHome]# sudo service jenkins status
jenkins (pid  7468) is running...

[root@varunHome]# sudo service jenkins stop
Shutting down Jenkins               [  OK  ]

[root@varunHome]# sudo service jenkins start
Starting Jenkins                    [  OK  ]

[root@varunHome]# sudo service jenkins restart
Shutting down Jenkins               [  OK  ]

Starting Jenkins                    [  OK  ]
[root@varunHome]#
```

**The folks who are using windows**

Open Console/Command line --> Go to your Jenkins installation directory. Execute the following commands respectively:

```js
To stop:
jenkins.exe stop

To start:
jenkins.exe start

To restart:
jenkins.exe restart
```

Answer (score 40):

On Windows, if you installed it as a service, go to Services (*Start* → *Run*: `services.msc`),
find Jenkins, right click → *Restart*.

If it does not help (UI is not responding) open the Windows Task Manager → *Processes*, kill the `java.exe` process, and restart the service once again.

Comment: trying to reach /safeRestart on windows will lead to: javax.servlet.ServletException: hudson.lifecycle.RestartNotSupportedException: Default Windows lifecycle does not support restart.

Comment: When `/safeRestart` is unavailable, use `/safeExit` before manually restarting.

Answer (score 37):

You have many options to restart Jenkins manually, but mainly two (URL or command line):

- **Alternative 1:** Using the Jenkins installation URL:

  `Jenkins_URL/restart`.

  > Example: http://jenkinsserver.com/restart

  This type of restart forces a restart without waiting for builds to complete.

  If you need to wait for the jobs endings you can use:

  `Jenkins_URL/safeRestart`.

  > Example: http://jenkinsserver.com/safeRestart
- **Alternative 2:** Using the command line, depending on your Jenkins installation.

  - If you're installing using **rpm** or **deb** package or you have the Jenkins installation in **Red Hat**, **Ubuntu**, or **Debian**, you can use these commands:
  - `sudo service jenkins restart`

    > This restart Jenkins in one step.
  - `sudo service jenkins stop` and `sudo service jenkins start`,

    > This restart Jenkins in two steeps.
    >
    > Note: if you need to check the Jenkins status, you can use this command: `sudo service jenkins status`
  - If you are using **CentOS**, you can use this command:

    ```
    sudo systemctl restart jenkins
    ```

    > Note: if you need to check the Jenkins status, you can use this command: `sudo systemctl status Jenkins`

Answer (score 20):

This can also be done using the [Jenkins CLI](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+CLI):

```
java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s http://[jenkins-server]/ restart
```

The `jenkins-cli.jar` file along with a full list of commands are available at `http://[jenkins-server]/cli`.

Answer (score 19):

If you're running Jenkins on Mac OS X then you can manually stop the service by executing this command:

```
sudo launchctl unload /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.jenkins-ci.plist
```

Comment: you can then restart using `load`

Answer (score 13):

If you want to just reload the configuration file, one can do

```
    <jenkins_url>/reload
```

This is quicker if you have made some small change in the configuration file, like `config.xml` directly in the file system or made copies of the job through the filesystem (not through the browser).

Answer (score 10):

Use [the command line interface](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+CLI):

```
java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s http://jenkins.example.com:8080/ -i /root/.ssh/id_rsa safe-restart
```

Answer (score 10):

It depends on how Jenkins has been started.

- As a service: `sudo service jenkins restart`, `sudo /etc/init.d/jenkins restart`, etc.
- As a web application in a Tomcat installation: restart your Tomcat, or just restart the application in Tomcat. Go to `http://<tomcat-server>:8080/manager/list` or after authentication hit `http://<tomcat-server>:8080/manager/stop?path=/myapp`+ `http://<tomcat-server>:8080/manager/start?path=/myapp`.
- Launched with just `java -jar`: kill it (`kill -9 <pid>`), and relaunch it.
- Launched with `java -jar`, but from a supervisor: `supervisorctl restart jenkins`

Comment: Just pick you use case nice answer !!

Comment: can we use these options to automatically identify if jenkins is not responding and can restart when its not responding ?

Answer (score 9):

#### On Windows

Go to the Jenkins installation, open the cmd and run:

- To stop:

  ```
   jenkins.exe stop
  ```
- To start:

  ```
   jenkins.exe start
  ```
- To restart:

  ```
   jenkins.exe restart
  ```

Answer (score 8):

If you are running Jenkins in FreeBSD(OS):

```
/usr/local/etc/rc.d/jenkins restart
```

Answer (score 8):

Sometimes there will be some stale Jenkins processes, so `ps -ef | grep jenkins` kill all of them. Restart as described in previous answers, and it will be clean.

```
ps -ef | grep jenkins
sudo kill -kill <pid>
```

Answer (score 6):

### For Mac

###Stop Jenkins###

```
sudo launchctl unload /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.jenkins-ci.plist
```

###Start Jenkins###

```
sudo launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.jenkins-ci.plist
```

For a homebrew installed jenkins, use the following:

Starting:

```
brew services restart jenkins-lts
```

Stopping:

```
brew services stop jenkins-lts
```

Answer (score 6):

For a modern Linux system that uses systemd (including CentOS, Debian):

```
sudo systemctl restart jenkins

sudo systemctl status Jenkins
```

Jenkins will be active and up and running on some PID.

Answer (score 5):

If you are able to access it in a web browser, just add `/restart`, for example, `localhost:8080/restart`.

If you are running it as a service then log in to your server and execute the command:

```
sudo service jenkins stop/start
```

Answer (score 4):

For restarting Jenkins manually using the browser:

Enter your `www.jenkins-ip/restart` 
(for example, `http://localhost:8080/restart`) in the browser. Jenkins will restart and load the login page automatically after restart.

Answer (score 3):

If it is deployed as a war file then restart the application server, for example, Tomcat.

Answer (score 3):

Several people have mentioned the need to restart the servlet container if Jenkins is not running as a standalone. But Tomcat (or what is being used) doesn't need to be restarted. Tomcat can force a restart of the Jenkins context if your Jenkins restart is hung.

But to address another comment, when you put Jenkins in the "shutting down" mode it will not actually shut down.  It stops new jobs from executing and place a giant red banner on the system pages so everyone knows that the administrator wants to take it down eventually. There are plugins to trigger a servlet container restart for that context after all builds are completed.

The alternative is to wait till the last running job completes, then manually kick over Jenkins from the container (or via the command line options that others have mentioned for the standalone Jenkins install).

Answer (score 3):

If it is in a Docker container, you can just restart your container. Let's assume the container name is `jenkins`, so you can do:

```
docker restart jenkins
```

Or

```
docker stop jenkins
docker start jenkins
```

Comment: Important! On docker - Jenkins data must be persistent (you might lose running jobs, resources, builds, data etc...) Therefore be cautious ,you better NOT using "restart" and DO use stop and start on docker image. the solution would be: sudo docker ps -> sudo docker stop <dockerImageID> -> sudo docker start <dockerImageID>

Answer (score 2):

JenkinURL/restart will do the restart.

---

```
/usr/local/etc/rc.d/jenkins restart
```

Comment: But `/usr/local/etc/rc.d/jenkin` is not a URL(?). Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 2):

From the terminal:

```
sudo service jenkins restart
```

Or `jenkinsurl/restart`.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below. It worked for me.

```
sudo service jenkins status
```

It will give you PID of Jenkins. Now do a

```
kill -15 [PID]

sudo service jenkins start
```

Comment: Wondering why you don't just do "(sudo) service jenkins restart" ?

Comment: Yes, absolutely correct but I have faced issue ,sometimes in which it doesn't worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

If nothing works then find the Jenkins process by

```
ps aux | grep java
```

and then kill it:

```
kill -9 [PID]

sudo service jenkins start
```

Edit : Look for the java process which is related to jenkins

Comment: quite dangerous to just search for java processes, don't you think? One should grep for something more jenkins specific imo.

Answer (score 1):

Browse http://[jenkins-server-url]/updateCenter/
and just check 'restart jenkins'

Answer (score 1):

#### Windows

Run `services.msc` and restart:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are running Jenkins as a server on a Windows machine, then open Task Manager and switch to the service tab. Search for Jenkins and restart it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have no permissions or access to the command line directly, you can do e.g. one of the following:

1. Create a job with shell/batch step that will trigger a restart from the Jenkins installation folder
2. Install/update some plugin while checking "restart after installation" (at least this works in old versions)

Both above are hacks, but I actively used them in a very restricted environment where no one wanted me to restart Jenkins, huh.

Answer (score -2):

`jenkins_url/restart` is the safest way of doing it.

For service- Service Jenkins restart.

Comment: What do you mean by *"For service- Service Jenkins restart."*?