# Locked out of Jenkins

Tags: security, jenkins

I enabled jenkins security thinking it would prompt me to create an account. I tried deleting and editing my config.xml file in c:/program files/jenkins but i'm not sure how to restart jenkins without having access.

Any help would be appreciated.

I'm running Jenkins on a windows server, recently updated to the latest version.

Comment: Why is this off topic??  Seems like a reasonable, programming related, question to me.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you don't have a lot of other configuration that you'd like to save, you can just delete `%JENKINS_HOME%/config.xml` and restart Jenkins to disable security.

Otherwise, edit `config.xml` and set the values inside the `<useSecurity>` tags to false, then restart Jenkins.

Comment: i tried deleting the config.xml in c:/program files/jenkins/ and restarting the jenkins service in windows but i was still locked out.

Comment: In addition I had to remove the authorizationStrategy and securityRealm elements. See: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Disable+security

Answer (score 4):

I had this exact issue today on my windows jenkins server.

Just removing the xml file and restarting did not work for me either. I had to:

- Stop the service.
- Check taskmanager to ensure the process is gone.
- Either edit the Config.XML file and change the useSecurity false or delete the config.xml file.
- Now start the service again

Answer (score 1):

You can try: [How to restart Jenkins manually?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8072700/jenkins-manual-restart)
or kill the process in taskmanager or do a taskkill in windows shell.

Here are the instructions to restart from command line:

Open Command Prompt.

Type one of the following: without qoutes

To stop a service, type:

```
net stop 'service'
```

To start a service, type:

```
net start 'service'
```

Also I think you may be looking in the wrong folder. Do you have a config.xml in

```
C:\Users\yourUserName\.jenkins?
```

Comment: killed the process in taskmanager still locked out of jenkins. Is there something else i need to do besides editing the config.xml?

Comment: is this line: '<useSecurity>true</useSecurity>' changed to false?

Comment: like @gareth_bowles said it should be whatever your %JENKINS_HOME% environment variable is. I put the path above because that's usually what it defaults to

Comment: I don't have a config in .jenkins should i?

Comment: According to the docs: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Administering+Jenkins there should be one in there if that is your jenkins home directory. you have to check the environment variable to be sure

Comment: where would i find the environment variable?

Comment: from command line just type `SET` to list them all.