# Jenkins freezes on build job, unable to ssh into virtual server to restart

Tags: nginx, jenkins, ubuntu-14.04

I'm new to Jenkins and it's hanging on a build job. I've read that a restart is in order. Unfortunately, I can't access the command line because the operation times out when I try to ssh into the virtual server. The server is running on Nginx/Ubuntu.

Is there anything I can do besides doing a hard reset of the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [SafeRestart](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/SafeRestart+Plugin) plugin or just restart Jenkins manually as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8072700/jenkins-manual-restart).