# Jenkins refuses to restart

Tags: jenkins, restart

Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8077830/51197), I have tried restarting a Jenkins instance using:

```
(jenkins_url)/safeRestart
```

and

```
(jenkins_url)/restart
```

Both failed with the following message:

> Jenkins cannot restart itself as currently configured.

Searching for `Jenkins cannot restart itself as currently configured` shows that the message appears [when the `app.lifecycle.canRestart` is on](https://github.com/albers/jenkins/blob/master/core/src/main/resources/jenkins/model/Jenkins/_restart.jelly#L32), but I am not sure how to set it.

Any idea how to make Jenkins restartable?

[image]

Comment: could be to user permissions somewhere?

Comment: No, I created the instance and I have all possible credentials.

Comment: Logs say much of use? You can restart Jenkins through other means.

Comment: What is OS , Jenkins version? hudson.lifecycle.Lifecycle and its implementations controls this. There may more information in the jenkins log. Please post it here

Comment: @Arran No, nothing useful there - no indication to the reboot request. I can obviously restart Jenkins externally, but I wonder what's the reason I can't do it internally.

Comment: @Jayan Ubuntu 14.04, Jenkins version 1.612.

Comment: Did you change any jenkins setting? User, jenkins home? I got similar error after removing permissions on jenkins war  and its parent.  That is probably expected: https://www.codatlas.com/github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/master/core/src/main/java/hudson/lifecycle/UnixLifecycle.java?line=76

Comment: @Jayan No, I haven't changed them in ages.

Answer (score 11):

Go to Manage Jenkins links.
Find the option "Install as Windows service".
Click on install.
Now (jenkins_url)/restart option will work. I faced this same issue now

Comment: I'm using the generic Java version and it throws an AccessDenied error when I try the above. If anyone else has this problem the solution is the open cmd/terminal as admin or sudo and then run Jenkins e.g. `java -jar jenkins.war`

Answer (score 3):

I installed Restart Safely plugin available in Jenkins Plugin Manager

Jenkins -> Manage Jenkins -> Manage Plugins -> Search for  Safe Restart -> Install it.

Then Go to Manage Jenkins -> "Install as Windows service" ->  install

Then Restart Safely appear on the Dashboard. Thanks to Shwetank Singh.

Answer (score 2):

If your Jenkins instance's servlet container does not support a web application restarting its own context, then this plugin cannot provide restart functionality, and the “Restart Safely” link will not appear.

I'm using Apache Tomcat v7.0.64 and after installing [SafeRestart Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/SafeRestart+Plugin) I got the same message as you had.

I think it would be much simpler for you if you just run Jenkins with the embedded container and the service wrapper

Answer (score 2):

I received such message when jenkins was started in command line 
(like java -jar jenkins.war)

After I started jenkins as a service (jenkins.exe install) and (jenkins.exe start)
it began to work.

Comment: Shwetank already said that. Your answer does not provide much more Information.

Answer (score 2):

Restart your command prompt in Administrator mode. So that you are having your all permission to run window as a service.

Answer (score 1):

To manually restart jenkins :

1. Go to task manager and end all the java instances .
2. Close command prompt .
3. Open command prompt again, point the current directory where jenkins.war file is available.
4. And fire the command java -jar jenkins.war .

I happen to face this problem where restart was required to update jenkins version , I tried by url but faced the error - jenkins cannot restart itself as currently configured. 
Tried above mentioned steps and it worked.