# Jenkins in Docker container cannot be restarted when host volume is mounted

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-volume

I am trying to prevent Jenkins data would be lost after remove container, so that I mapped host dir for container(`-v /home/jenkins/data:/var/jenkins_home`). But I was not able to run container. The error I got was:

`Can not write to /var/jenkins_home/copy_reference_file.log. Wrong volume permissions?
touch: cannot touch '/var/jenkins_home/copy_reference_file.log': Permission denied`

So I needed to add permission for that folder (`/home/jenkins/data`) or run container as `jenkins` user: `-u jenkins`.

After add this flag Jenkins is running and data after remove and recreate container is not lost. But I cannot restart Jenkins (`http://jenkinshost.local/restart`). I got following error: `Jenkins cannot restart itself as currently configured.` at the Jenkins app. This error does not occurs when I not mount host directory. I cannot install any plug-in and so on..

I am running container by:

`sudo docker run -v /home/jenkins/data:/var/jenkins_home -p 80:8080 -u jenkins jenkins/jenkins`

or

`sudo docker run -v /home/jenkins/data:/var/jenkins_home -p 80:8080 -u jenkins jenkins/jenkins`

Do you have any solution for this issue?

**SOLUTION**

The solution for this problem is creating volume on host instead of mapping specific folder:

`docker run -p 80:8080 -p 50000:50000 -v jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home -d jenkins/jenkins:lts`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jenkins refuses to restart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32790081/jenkins-refuses-to-restart)

Comment: No, there is no this option. I installed `Safe Restart` plug-in but the same result.

Comment: check this https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/issues/177