# I am not able to safe-restart jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, devops, jenkins-cli

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9EcRB.png)

I am not able to safe-restart jenkins. I need help.

Comment: Do not paste an image if text; especially if it does not information. Instead, provide an approporiate level of dwtail, like how you launvh Jenkins. Also, don't "demand help"; explain what you did and what's  your problem and you'll usually get assistance or a response. Jenkins does not support restart unless running as a service (Windows services or daemon)

Comment: Ohh sorry my bad. Im new to stackoverflow... And thank you brother.

Comment: No problem. Suggest you read [How do I ask a good question? ](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also suggest [some research](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32790081/jenkins-refuses-to-restart) before posting next q.