# config.xml getting replaced on jenkins restart

Tags: security, jenkins, authorization, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I want to disable security in jenkins. I stopped the service, edited **$JENKINS_HOME/config.xml** as given in https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Disable+security and https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Disable+security

But whenever i restart, the content is getting replaced with initial value. I tried doing the same in ~/.jenkins directory also. But still everytime i restart, its getting replaced. Not able to understand why this is happening.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you restarting your server??? Are you following safe restart procedures?

Comment: I'm having the same issue.  I've restarted using systmectl and the /restart rest command.  It resets my config.xml

Comment: @SVMadhavaReddy Restarting didn't help.. :(

Comment: @Wanderer Restarting didn't help.. :(

Comment: @Sarath. No.  I've started tracking this issue here as well.
https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-55088

Comment: @Sarath Don't use system ctl, instead use <jenkins_url>/restart. Try with this and let me know once. You can use <Jenkins_url>/reload to reload the configuration also without restarting it.

Comment: @SVMadhavaReddy neither that worked..

Comment: I tried changing the xml while running jenkins itself. Its working fine. Then I tried reload config from disk option, it reloaded and its working with new values. So you are doing somewhere wrong. debug it.

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/34142999/5003256](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34142999/5003256) Take a look at this.

Answer (score 0):

had the same issue. im not 100% sure, but in multiple tries i found that:

```
cp -f edited_config.xml /var/lib/jenkins/config.xml
sudo systemctl restart jenkins.service
sudo ./install_plugins.sh $(cat plugins.txt | tr '\n' ' ')
sudo systemctl restart jenkins.service
```

bug did not happened

but when i didnt restart jenkins between config file editing and install plugins, i sew this bug.

```
cp -f edited_config.xml /var/lib/jenkins/config.xml
sudo ./install_plugins.sh $(cat plugins.txt | tr '\n' ' ')
sudo systemctl restart jenkins.service
```

hope it is helpful