# How to set / connect jenkins slave agent back on previous machine

Tags: jenkins, agent, jenkins-agent

Is there any possibility to set a slave agent back to the previous machine without deleting the agent / node? Will the node be completely deleted if i'm deleting the agent?

In my case for example, if someone has installed by accident the agent via "Launch"-Button (Java WS) on an other machine. But this other machine is not intended to have an connection with the agent (because of missing files and wrong user).

He got the option displayed to add an agent for his current used machine (wrong machine) which led to the problem, but now i don't see this option ("Launch"-Button) anymore to reconnect the agent with the previous necessary machine.

[Maybe this could be a resolution?](http://mindthe.net/devices/2013/11/01/6-steps-to-update-jenkins-slave-agents-on-windows/)

Already tried:
Using following command line on required slave machine in C:\Jenkins:

```
java -jar slave.jar -jnlpUrl http://<<build-server:port>>/computer/<<agent name>>/slave-agent.jnlp
```

Execution wasn't successful..

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to restart Jenkins manually?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8072700/how-to-restart-jenkins-manually)