# How to login to jenkins when LDAP server is not available?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I did setup jenkins with LDAP and i'm able to login. But when i stop the LDAP server I'm unable to login to jenkins using jenkin's local user account. Also always editing the config.xml is not a good idea to change security settings. Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What Ive done in a previous role -  is a copy of Jenkins config that allows admin & a selection of other users access when LDAP is down.

When LDAP is down , I switch manually

```
mv config.xml config.ldap.xml
mv config.internal.xml config.xml
```

Restart Jenkins ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/8077830/1935094 )

The config.internal.xml was setup before I configured LDAP. You could also backup your config.xml , configure Jenkins for internal user access  , copy that off and copy back in your LDAP configured config.xml.

Anyway - the idea is that you can still get in , run jobs etc until LDAP is back.

Ive had thoughts about automating it , if LDAP is detected as down ( you could run a lookup periodically , then switch if need be...

Comment: I guess for now, this will be the better option. Thank you for support.

Comment: No problem , its not perfect , but it does give you an access option. Remember to backup your config files off server too.

Comment: this is unhelpful because you are not sharing the relevant piece that configures auth. Mind doing that?

Comment: @VincentGerris Am unsure what you mean. I take a backup before LDAP config and use that when I need to logon if LDAP is down. You need to take care of LDAP config on your instance and this will be different from environment to environment so I didnt need to share that. ( I only shared the concept of before / after LDAP config file usage ) . Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

As of now, local user login is not possible when LDAP enabled. Jenkins internal user database is automatically disabled when you activate LDAP authentication.

Few Jenkins JIRA to get more details on this.

1. [JENKINS-3404](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-3404)
2. [JENKINS-29162](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-29162)

There is no other way except editing ~.jenkins/config.xml.

Answer (score 0):

Better option is to migrate(LDAP user) to Jenkins own user database.

Comment: Hi @Aakizone, how to migrate LDAP users to Jenkins own user database?

Answer (score 0):

FOR FUTURE:
- Add a secondary LDAP server on Jenkins host.
- Remember to check "Ignore if unavailable" on the first LDAP.

More [info](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/jenkins-nexus3-authentication-authorization-through-ldap-russo)