# How to extract a variable(username,ID) from Jenkins output

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

**This is the output I got**:

"Successfully created scratch org: oopopoooppooop, username: test+color@example.com"

**when I run the following script:**

```groovy
echo "1. Creating Scratch Org"
def orgStatus = bat returnStdout: true, script: "sfdx force:org:create --definitionfile ${PROJECT_SCRATCH_PATH} --durationdays 30 --setalias ${SCRATCH_ORG_NAME} -v DevHub "

if (!orgStatus.contains("Successfully created scratch org")) {
    error "Scratch Org creation failed"
} else {
    echo orgStatus
}
```

Now I need to extract scratch org ID and username from the output separately and store it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to restart Jenkins manually?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8072700/how-to-restart-jenkins-manually)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression:

```groovy
def regEx = 'Successfully created scratch org: (.*?), username: (.*)'
def match = orgStatus =~ regEx

if( match ) {
    println "ID: " + match[0][1]
    println "username: " + match[0][2]
}
```

Here the operator `=~` applies the regular expression to the input and the result is stored in `match`.

**[Live Demo](https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5147733983756288)**

Comment: @VikramReddy I don't understand, username is available in `match[0][2]`.

Comment: @VikramReddy The question mark is required to extract only the minimum number of characters up to the comma. Otherwise we would extract too much, when username contains comma. Username is located at end of string, so we don't need question mark there.

Comment: @VikramReddy You can pass it for a parameter, it depends on the command.

Comment: If I want to use in the following command                           sfdx force:org:create  match[0][2] , This is the way or should I add "$"
 sign before

Comment: @VikramReddy `${match[0][2]}`. Personally I would store username in a variable to make code more readable: `def username = match[0][2]`, then `sfdx force:org:create $username`

Comment: @VikramReddy This is not much different from previous problem. You may have issues with the square brackets, which have to be escaped with a backslash in the RegEx: `\[`. If you can't find a solution, you may ask a new question, presenting what you have tried so far. But this is more a Groovy / RegEx question, it doesn't relate to Jenkins at all.