# How to start the jenkins stopped from UI

Tags: jenkins

I stopped my jenkins from ui by typing below.Now, How can I bring it up? I dont have sudo or root access to start the services on the unix machine where it is installed and running as service.is there any other way?

```
<serverurl>/exit
```

Comment: can you check if these question has the answer which you are looking for ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8072700/how-to-restart-jenkins-manually

Comment: not really. I had a look at this already

Comment: You have installed jenkins using jenkins package right ?

Comment: yes correct . I see only way is to use service start jenkins. is there ant other way?

Comment: I guess u will need the sudo access afaik

Comment: I have requested for that as I could not find any other solution.