# How to resolve stuck "Uninstallation pending" of Jenkins plugin?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have a deprecated Jenkins plugin installed (WMI Windows Agents Plugin, v1.8.1), and I'm trying to uninstall it.

###### Problem

When I uninstall the plugin from the Jenkins web UI, it gets stuck at "Uninstallation pending"  no matter how long I wait.

###### What I Tried

When I do a [safe restart](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8077830/7931817) after a long wait, the UI shows that the plugin is still installed, as if I had not attempted an uninstall. I also tried disabling the plugin before attempting another uninstall—still stuck at pending uninstallation. Doing a yet another safe-restart after a long wait doesn't work either.

Comment: Did you first uninstall/delete any nodes configured to use WMI agents? It won't be able to uninstall if still "in use".

Comment: @IanW There were already no nodes left that use WMI agents even before attempting to uninstall the plugin.

Answer (score 12):

After you click uninstall, while the status is "Uninstallation pending",
click on Available Plugins and without selecting any plugins click on Download now and Install after Restart.
For some reason this completes the uninstallation

Comment: Tried this but the plugin still isn't removed. :(

Comment: In my exact case it worked like a charm. Additional context for those interested: Jenkins in a docker container with data stored as a volume.

Comment: That works. You need to then tick the box to instruct Jenkins to restart. Alternatively, i'm guessing you can just restart the Jenkins process manually in the command line (systemctl restart jenkins)

Comment: I have the same issue, and this trick doesn't work for me either with the LTS version. The plugins come back after a restart, safe or unsafe.

Comment: Also with Jenkins 2.426.2, there's no more "Download now and install after restart" button on the "Available plugins" page. There's now a "Donwload/Install" button on the top-right, but it's disabled if you don't select anything.

Answer (score 0):

I initially couldn't uninstall the WMI Windows Agents Plugin on Jenkins 2.375.2 either.

[This comment on `JENKINS-70454`](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-70454?focusedCommentId=434383&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-434383) suggested that upgrading to Jenkins 2.375.3 might help, and indeed:
I could uninstall the plugin as expected after upgrading.

---

FWIW: I assume that [`hudson.PluginManager#considerDetachedPlugin`](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/blob/jenkins-2.375.2/core/src/main/java/hudson/PluginManager.java#L611-L631) was somehow responsible for keeping that plugin, as

```
journalctl -ujenkins | grep windows
```

showed me

> hudson.PluginManager#considerDetachedPlugin: Loading a detached plugin as a dependency: /var/lib/jenkins/plugins/windows-slaves.jpi

after every reboot (but to be honest, I don't know much about detached plugins).

Answer (score 0):

You should install the *Safe Restart Plugin*. Then go to *dashboard*
-> *manage jenkins* -> *available plugins* -> *Safe Restart Plugin* -> *install this plugin*. Finally, login anew to your jenkins server.